# Can't fix rmarkdown Error in str2lang(x) : attempt to use zero-length variable name

Tags: r, r-markdown

I keep getting this error (Error in str2lang(x) : attempt to use zero-length variable name) but it's only specific to one line of code. I've been checking many different places for a solution and everyone seems to be suggesting it's the misplacement of a ` or that it's because R is reading it as a normal .r file and not .rmd. If that were the case, I think it wouldn't read the rest of my code right? It's just this single line. I'll include my whole chunk:

```
# Read in data, and check data set

#Read in data & set WD:
# I'm going to read in my .csv file and rename it so it's shorter

setwd("D:/Users/samik/Documents/R_NEW/Data_Analysis_WD/Assignment_3")
pollen <- read.csv("D:/Users/samik/Documents/R_NEW/Data_Analysis_WD/Assignment_3/pollinators(5).csv")

#The following code is based off the module 2 assignment

#Missing values
which(is.na(pollen)==TRUE, arr.ind = TRUE)
#No missing values! We can move on

#Outliers (did badly using boxplots last module so let's try cook's distance method instead)

#Need a linear model to do it
model.a = lm(success ~ AREA, data = pollen)

#The cooks.distance() function
cooks <- cooks.distance(model.a)

#If it's >4x the mean, it's influential
inf.val <- which(cooks >= 4*mean(cooks))
pollen[inf.val,]

#Need to plot cook's distance now - This is taken out of Dr. Beatty's mini-lecture
plot(cooks, pch="*", cex=2, main="Influential Values by Cook's distance") +
abline(h = 4*mean(cooks, na.rm=T), col="red") +
text(x=1:length(cooks)+1, y=cooks, labels=ifelse(cooks>4*mean(cooks, na.rm=T),names(cooks),""), col="red") 

#autocorrelation

#We are going to check for correlation and then use a package to check for VIF and tolerance at the same time. We're only looking at AREA and success here.
cor(pollen)

#Check the VIF and tolerance using the lm we already made
library(olsrr)

model.a = lm(success ~ AREA, data = pollen)
**ols_vif_tol(model.a)**

#Homoscedasticity (good)

#Normality (good) 

# Calculate median success

# Plot relationship to see if a linear model might be appropriate
```

I tried installing olssr again and restarting R (no luck). It is only that single line of code (bolded; ols_vif_tol(model.a)) that is giving my error. It's driving me completely insane. I HAVE to use this method because it's a school assignment. I used it before in an rmarkdown file without issues. I don't have any idea what the issue is.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not really possible to answer without knowing the full input, but `**ols_vif_tol(model.a)**` is not syntactic R code so it's possible it may be the cause.

Comment: Please reduce the code as much as possible. At the moment there is still a lot of irrelevant stuff contained.

Comment: The error can be reproduced (outside of rmarkdown) with `library(olsrr); model.a <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars); ols_vif_tol(model.a)` .  But okay with `model.a <- lm(mpg ~ wt + disp, mtcars)` e.g. more than one predictor. Which I suppose makes sense that more than one predictor is needed as examining at collinearity. But not a helpful error message